# Segmentation fault using fgets()

Tags: c, arrays, fgets

I am making a basic program, and decided to use functions, and pointers, in the first input I have the choice of typing either, "kitchen", or "upstairs", however when I use `fgets()` I am getting a segmentation fault, and have no idea why. I tried to print out the string to see if I was getting the correct output, of course due to the segmentation fault it's not happening.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char one(char *oOne[]);
void two();
void three();

int main() {
    char *oOne[10], oTwo[10], oThree[10]; // Options one, two, and three.
    puts("WELCOME TO ASAD'S ADVENTURE");
    puts("");
    one(oOne);
    return 0;
}

char one(char *oOne[]) {
    puts("You are in a creepy house! Would you like to go \"upstairs\", or into the \"kitchen\"?");

    printf("\n> ");

    if (fgets(*oOne, sizeof *oOne, stdin) == NULL) { // Receiving the input from the user, and removing the \n caused by fgets().
        puts("EOF Occurred");
        return 1;
    }

    *oOne[strcspn(*oOne, "\n")] = 0;
    printf("%s\n", *oOne);
    // puts(*oOne);
}
```

Here is the output I am receiving:

```
WELCOME TO ASAD'S ADVENTURE

You are in a creepy house! Would you like to go "upstairs", or into the "kitchen"?

> kitchen
Segmentation fault
```

How can I fix the segmentation fault?

Comment: Did you try running this through `gdb` or `valgrind`?

Comment: You have an array of `char*` (`oOne`), which is an array of pointers that have not been initialized. You need to allocate memory for them. You also need to double check what `sizeof *oOne` gives you.

Comment: also, "sizeof *oOne" will return the size of the pointer (4 or 8 bytes), not the size of the buffer you pass in.  You need to pass the buffer size in as a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A character string in C is of type pointer-to-character, e.g.,:

```
char *oOne;
```

Or an array-of-character, if you want to statically allocate your memory:

```
char oOne[10];
```

But *not* a pointer-to-array-of-character, which is what you have:

```
char *oOne[10];
```

You need:

```
char oOne[10];
```

And then:

```
one(oOne);
```

And then modify your `one` function with proper types:

```
char one(char *oOne)
{
    if (fgets(oOne, sizeof oOne, stdin) == NULL)
    {
            puts("EOF Occurred");
            return 1;
    }

    *(oOne + strcspn(oOne, "\n")) = 0;

    printf("%s\n", oOne);


}
```

Although I would pass in an explicit length, rather than using
`sizeof`, because this won't work with dynamically allocated strings:

```
car one(char *oOne, int len)
{
    if (fgets(oOne, len, stdin) == NULL)
    {
            puts("EOF Occurred");
            return 1;
    }

    // etc...
}
```

Comment: `char *oOne[10];` is an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array. And `sizeof oOne` doesn't work here regardless of whether `oOne` was dynamically allocated or not.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, +1 , I didn't know that about pointers, and arrays!

Comment: "A character string in C is of type pointer-to-character" mis-leads in that a string is neither a pointer nor a type.  A C string is a character array ending with a null character.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are getting a segfault because your are dereferencing oOne in `if (fgets(*oOne, sizeof *oOne, stdin) == NULL)`. Using the right left rule on `char *oOne[]` you get that oOne is an array of pointers to characters, so what you have is an array of Strings rather than a String. So to use fgets you want to have a single String in your case rather than an array of strings. So instead define oOne as `char oOne[BUFSIZ]`. This gives you a string that at max lets you take in bufsiz characters, which is the size of the buffer and you can't go over this.

So to fix your code it would look something like this:

change `char *oOne[10], oTwo[10], oThree[10]` to `char oOne[10], oTwo[10], oThree[10]`

change `char one(char *oOne[])` to `char one(char * oOne)`

change `fgets(*oOne, sizeof *oOne, stdin)` to `fgets(oOne, sizeof oOne, stdin)`

change `*oOne[strcspn(*oOne, "\n")]` to `oOne[strcspn(oOne, "\n")]`

This way you are interacting with oOne as a string (array of characters) rather than an array of character pointers. For more information on how defining variables in see works take a look at the right-left rule here http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html.